# Visualize tree structure of HTTP GET requests in server log files using R 3.2.3

Tags: r, tree

I'm relatively new to R, and I've volunteered to try to use it to determine which files on an old media server are still being used, and which aren't. I have access to the server logs, and specifically the cs-uri-stem column. Here's what I get when I type head(uridata):

```
1: /favicon.ico
2: /courses/filipino/Kuwentong_Pambata/Isinaayos_ni_Leslie_Joy_Cruz.html
3: /courses/filipino/Kuwentong_Pambata/Isinaayos_ni_Leslie_Joy_Cruz_files/Isinaayos_ni_Leslie_Joy_Cruz.css
4: /courses/filipino/Kuwentong_Pambata/Isinaayos_ni_Leslie_Joy_Cruz_files/Isinaayos_ni_Leslie_Joy_CruzMoz.css
5: /courses/filipino/Kuwentong_Pambata/Isinaayos_ni_Leslie_Joy_Cruz_files/shapeimage_1.jpg
6: /courses/filipino/Kuwentong_Pambata/Isinaayos_ni_Leslie_Joy_Cruz_files/WidgetCommon.js
```

Obviously, the samples in this case are all coming from one set of folders, but in fact, there are thousands of different folders and languages, all of which have their own websites. I'm interested in being able to visualize this as a tree, to see which folders/languages are still getting usage.

I've looked at the data.tree package for R, which I thought would be ideal. I've tried to follow the guide at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html#trees-in-data.tree, but when I type "as.Node(uridata)", R gives me the error message "Error in myrow[[pathName]] : subscript out of bounds". I've searched online for that error, and understand that it occurs when you try to call a subscript that isn't in the original data set, but I don't understand why it is happening here.

Can anyone give me some guidance as to why I'm running into this problem, or how I can solve it? I'm running R 3.2.3 on OS 10.11.3, using RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. I didn't read the data.tree guide closely enough the first time. In order to use as.Node() to transform my HTML paths into a tree, I needed to add a column, $pathString, with that same data using the following command:

```
uridata$pathString <- paste("..", uridata$cs.uri.stem, sep = "/")
```

That creates a "pathString" column for the data. Then, as.Node(uridata) works properly.